# How does the Split Ray metamagic feat apply to the Light of Lunia spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, targeting, metamagic

I stumbled across the Light of Lunia spell in the *Spell Compendium* (p. 132), and was wondering how exactly Metamagic would apply to it. Split Ray in particular interests me, as I would love a way to get an additional ray out of it.

The Light of Lunia spell description says:

> Evocation [Good, Light]
> Level: Celestia 1, Cleric 1, Sorcerer/Wizard 1,
> Components: V, S
> Casting Time: 1 standard action
> Range: Medium (100 ft. + 10 ft./level)
> Target: You and up to two rays; see text
> Duration: 10 minutes/level (D) or until discharged; see text
> Saving Throw: None
> Spell Resistance: Yes; see text
>
> You invoke the powers of good and you begin to glow with the silver light of fabled Lunia, the first layer of the Seven Mounting Heavens of Celestia.
>
> The silvery radiance created by this spell emanates from you in a 30-foot radius, and dim light extends for an additional 30 feet.
>
> Beginning one turn after you cast this spell, you can choose to expend some or all of the light of Lunia as a ray of light. You must succeed on a ranged touch attack with the ray to strike a target. You can make a single ranged touch attack that deals 1d6 points of damage, or 2d6 points of damage against undead or evil outsiders, with a range of 30 feet. Spell resistance applies to this attack. This dims your silvery radiance to half (15-foot light, with dim light for an additional 15 feet). You can choose to fire one additional ray with the same characteristics either on the same round or on a subsequent round. Firing the second ray quenches your radiance and ends the spell.

Comment: If you're curious as to how a couple of metamagic feats specifically interact with this spell, please list those specific metamagic feats. (I know that the Split Ray feat is one.) I fear that the question's asking too much for answers to explain how each of the nearly 100 metamagic feats interact with this spell!

Comment: There's no reason to ask each question together rather than separately. If you want to know about feats other than split ray, you should ask more questions and get more rep.

Comment: Rather than quoting the entire spell description, you should quote only the relevant/necessary parts of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Split Ray feat from *Complete Arcane* (p. 83) states:

> You can cause any ray spell to fire one additional ray beyond the number normally allowed.

So for *light of lunia*, you would be able to fire three rays instead of two. Note that the additional ray, also due to the rules of Split Ray, must be fired simultaneously with one of the other two normal rays. You would not be able to, for example, fire rays on each of three separate rounds.